# Uploading file to S3 bucket

Tags: windows, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload file from my local machine to S3 bucket but I am getting an error "The user-provided path ~Downloads/index.png does not exist."

> aws s3 cp ~Downloads/index.png s3://asdfbucketasdf/Temp/index_temp.png

File with name index does exists on my Downloads.

Comment: Try `aws s3 cp ~/Downloads/index.png s3://asdfbucketasdf/Temp/index_temp.png`, assuming index.png exists under your user's Downloads directory.

Comment: Tried it still getting the same error.

Comment: type `ls ~/Downloads/index.png`. Do you see the file?

Comment: Since I am on windows cmd prompt the above cli does not work, but when I go to downloads and check this file exists.

Comment: Type `aws s3 cp C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\Downloads\index.png s3://asdfbucketasdf/Temp/index_temp.png` on Windows.

Comment: Thank you it helped.

Comment: Awesome. I noticed that you have asked some questions on StackOverflow but not accepted any answer provided to you. It'd be great if you could put closure to your question by going to each of your questions and finding an answer that best suits your needs. There'll be a tick mark by the answer. Clicking that will indicate that the answer was helpful to your question. It's not a requirement. It's totally your choice.

Comment: Sure, I will do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer might be helpful to some users new to AWS CLI on different platforms.

**If you are on Linux or Linux-like systems**, you can type:

```
aws s3 cp ~/Downloads/index.png s3://asdfbucketasdf/Temp/index_temp.png
```

Note that `~Downloads` means a username called Downloads. What you would want is `~/Downloads`, which means Downloads directory under current user's home directory.

You can type out your path fully like so (assuming your home directory was `/home/matt`):

```
aws s3 cp /home/matt/Downloads/index.png s3://asdfbucketasdf/Temp/index_temp.png
```

**If you are on Windows**, you can type:

```
aws s3 cp C:\Users\matt\Downloads\index.png s3://asdfbucketasdf/Temp/index_temp.png
```

or you can use `~` like feature in Windows:

```
aws s3 cp %USERPROFILE%\Downloads\index.png s3://asdfbucketasdf/Temp/index_temp.png
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows and CLI version 2:

```
aws s3 cp "helloworld.txt" s3://testbucket
```